# Use of Myhill-Nerode Theorem to prove minimal number of states

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

I'm confused about how we can use the Myhill-Nerode Theorem to solve this problem, some pointers would be very helpful

Let $Σ = {\{a, b}\}$ and $C_k=Σ^*aΣ^{k-1}$

Prove that for each k, no DFA can recognize $C_k$ with fewer than $2^k$ states.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find $2^k$ words which belong to different equivalence classes of the Myhill–Nerode relation. Put differently, you need to find a collection of $2^k$ words such that for any two of them $x \neq y$ there is a word $z$ such that $xz \in L$ and $yz \notin L$ or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

(I know, ancient question)

Consider the $2^k$ different strings in $\Sigma^*$ of length $k$, and consider which of those strings are equivalent to which other of those strings under the equivalence relation used in the Myhill-Nerode theorem.

Obviously, strings that end in `a` aren't equivalent to strings which end in `b` because if you attach a suffix of length $k-1$, the strings that end in `a` are in $C_k$ but the strings that end in `b` aren't.

Similarly, strings with the second-to-last letter of `a` aren't equivalent to strings with the second-to-last letter `b` because of what happens with a suffix of length $k-2$, and so on.

Therefore none of these strings are equivalent to each other, and we're done.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the language ${C_k}$, and let $\sim_{C_k}\subseteq \Sigma\times \Sigma$ denote the Myhill-Nerode equivalence relation w.r.t to $C_k$. As the number of Myhill-Nerode equivalence classes bounds from below the size of the minimal DFA that recognizes $C_k$, it is sufficient to bound the number of Myhill-Nerode equivalnce classes from below. Specifically, we show that the relation $\sim_{C_k}$ has at least $2^k$ equivalence classes.
Consider all words $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_{2^k} \in \Sigma^k$, thus, every word $w_i$ is of length $k$ and consists only of letters from $ \Sigma = \{ a, b\}$. We claim that for all $1 \leq i < j \leq 2^k$, it holds that $[w_i]_{\sim_{C_k}} \neq [w_j]_{\sim_{C_k}}$ ($w_i$ and $w_j$ are not in the same equivalence class) , and hence there are at least $2^k$ equivalence classes:

As the words $w_i$ and $w_j$ are of length $k$, we can write them as $w_i = c_1\cdot c_2 \cdots c_{k}, w_j = d_1\cdot d_2 \cdots d_{k}$, where $c_l, d_l \in \Sigma$ for all $l\in [k]$. Recall that the words $w_i$ and $w_j$ are distinct, and let $l \leq k$ be the maximal index such that $c_l\neq d_l$. Assume w.l.o.g that $c_l = a$ and $d_l = b$. Then, any word $z$ of length $l-1$ is such that $w_i \cdot z = c_1\cdot c_2 \cdots c_l \cdot c_{l+1} \cdots c_{k}  \cdot z$ has $c_l =a$ as its $k$'th letter from the end, and $w_j \cdot z = d_1\cdot d_2 \cdots d_l \cdot d_{l+1} \cdots d_{k}  \cdot z$ has $d_l = b$ as its $k$'th letter from the end. Hence, every word $z$ of length $l-1$ is such that $w_i \cdot z \in C_k$, but $w_j\cdot z \notin C_k$, and thus $[w_i]_{\sim_{C_k}} \neq [w_j]_{\sim_{C_k}}$.